# Sharepoint multiple list update

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm creating three approved software lists for my company with SharePoint. One is the general list for all associates the next is the restricted list which will contain software like wireshark that only certain people should have access to and the last is the master list which will be a combination of the other two lists.

What would be ideal is being able to add the software to the master list and have it update the other two lists automagically. The unique key will of course be the software title. The field that will determine which list the row will be added to is the the [group] field. (This is where the uncertainty comes in) There will be 4 values that can go into this [group] field they are: restricted, general, engineering, media.

I would like to have the rows with "restricted" go to the restricted list, obviously, and everything else go to the general list.

I'm very new to SharePoint (~1 week) and I'm trying to simplify this process as much as possible. I'm continuing to read and watch the videos to lean more however, I understand this is a complex application. I thought I'd pose this question to people with more experience than myself to find if it's even possible. If not I'll be able to change my train of thought sooner.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a question for https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

But -- what I would do in your situation is only use 1 list and make multiple views.

Each view can be filtered by a different criteria (like your group column in this case) then instead of having 3 distinct lists, you can display or have a link for each view (they all get their own URI in SharePoint) seperately.

This way you only ever have to update 1 list, and you avoid the overhead/complexity of trying to copy into other lists with event recievers or workflows or something else.

If someone reading this needs instructions on views:
You can create/switch views from the 'List' or 'Library' tab when you're viewing the list. Then when you add the list to a web part page, you can select which view to use in the web part properties window.

Comment: This was it. Perfect for what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you so much friend!